# Gulp: convert java scripts extension in index.html

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-html-replace

I am trying to convert java scripts extension '.js' to '.js.gz'. For this i chose [gulp-html-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace) module. But i am unable to get the desired result. For below example i am using two scripts but i have more.

index.html (Before):

```
<!-- build:js -->
    <script src="routing_components/app-routing/app-routing.component.js"></script>
    <script src="routing_components/home-routing/home-routing.component.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

index.html (After gulp index.html should be like this):

```
<script src="routing_components/app-routing/app-routing.component.js.gz"></script>
<script src="routing_components/home-routing/home-routing.component.js.gz"></script>
```

But instead i am getting this after running gulp task

```
<script src="index.js.gz"></script>
```

Gulp task:

```
gulp.task('index_gzip', function () {
    gulp.src('app/index.html')
        .pipe(htmlreplace({
            js: {
                src: null,
                tpl: '<script src="%f.js.gz"></script>'
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function (file) {
            return file.base;
        }))
});
```

If somebody know better module for this kind of task, please recommend. And please help to correct my gulp task

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace). But I don't know why regex grouping Not working properly.

```
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
gulp.task('index_gzip', function () {
    gulp.src('app/index.html')
        .pipe(replace(/(<script.*?src=\")(.*?).js\"/g, '$1$2.js.gz"'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function (file) {
            return file.base;
        }))
});
```

Comment: Is this will change every script in app/index.html. What about if you want to change specific scripts.